# Share point list validation on prefilling previous column before the next column is filled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a Share Point list with multiple columns. I need to put a validation that Col3 cannot be filled till Col1 and Col2 are filled. And maybe add similar validation later like Col5 cannot be filled Till Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4 are filled.

[Sharepoint List Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZot.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this for modern experience look these links

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/conditional-formula-to-show-hide-columns-in-sharepoint-list

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-hide-a-field-in-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-with-the-conditional-formula/

https://blog.jijitechnologies.com/show-hide-column-based-on-condition-in-sharepoint

Steps

1. Click **New** button on list
2. Click **Edit Form** and select **Edit columns** in right edit pane
3. On your **COL3 column** click **3 dots (...)** and then click **Edit conditional formula**

Conditional formula to see COL3 if COL1 and COL2 have values

```
=if([$_x0043_OL1]!='' && [$_x0043_OL2]!='','true', 'false')
```

You need internal name of columns. **_x0043_OL1** is internal name of **COL1** column.

To find internal column name, go to **List settings** and click on column. In URL get name after **&Field=** for ex. **&Field=_x0043_OL1** for COL1